# Deminormal and Gorenstein

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, minimal-model-program

Let X be an irreducible deminormal variety such that the normalisation is Gorenstein. Does it follow that X is also Gorenstein?

for deminormal definition, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02002.pdf

Comment: What does deminormal mean?

Comment: G1, S2, and seminormal I believe.